# How to properly receive string from a function in c

Tags: c, string

I have a function like below:

```
char * function(char a)
{
  char data[5];
  char *hData;
  sprintf(data,"%02X",a);
  data[5] = '\0';
  hData = data;
  return hData;
}
```

So basically a is `170` and I need to convert it into its hex equivalent `AA` and return it. After sprintf it gets converted into `AA` but I was not able to return the array so I saved it into string `hData` and then return it. `hData` contains `AA` at the time of return.

In my main function, I am receiving it like below:

```
char *hex;
hex = function(buf[0]);  //This line gives warning
```

hex contains data `AA` but then why it gives warning.

Warning says:

```
assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Comment: you return pointer to local variable (*data*) in function. after function return - it will be below stack pointer. as result can be modified at any time (or after first another function call). this is of course error. the best - you need pass pointer to string to function as parameter. so allocate string in caller function. as alternative you need allocate string from heap or another storage in function, for return it. but return address of local variable in stack - this is error

Comment: The error message indicates thatr you didn't declare `function()` before you called it.  That's a compilation error in C99 or later — you must be using a compiler in C90 mode (where it was permissible, but the compiler assumed otherwise undeclared functions return an `int` — which leads to bugs when the function returns a pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a string, you must use dynamic memory allocation. Like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * function(char a)
{
  char *hData = malloc(5);  // Allocate memory

  // Use hData just as if it was declared like hData[5]
  sprintf(hData, "%02X", a);
  hData[3] = 0;

  return hData;  // Return a pointer to the allocated memory
}

int main() 
{
    // Use it like
    char* s = function('a');
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The posted code returns a pointer to a local variable (i.e. `data`). That is invalid as the local variable goes out of scope (i.e. doesn't exists anymore) as soon as the function returns. Therefore you need to use `malloc` as memory allocated with `malloc` is valid until you explicit frees it.

Comment: it still gives warning initialization makes pointer from integer without cast

Comment: have you include `stdlib.h` ? Like: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: I am compiling with gcc. (ubuntu)

Comment: @Doe: I have updated the answer to show all my code. I compile it with: `gcc -Wall code.c` I don't get any warnings.

Comment: @Doe: You can try `char *hData = (char*)malloc(5);` but that should **not** be necessary (and some says that it is a bad habbit).

Comment: Although it seems to work properly. But I do not know why it is giving warning. I am using eclipse in ubuntu with gcc. Is there any way to remove warning.

Comment: @Doe: I'm not sure how to remove the warning as it should **not** be there! Did you try what I suggested in the comment above?

Comment: @Doe: Do you know exactly which line that gives the warning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144715/discussion-between-doe-and-4386427).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several bugs:

- You're returning a pointer to the `data` array, which is a local variable within the function.  After the function returns, it's no longer valid to dereference that pointer.  (It may *seem* to work, but it can also crash your program or cause it to misbehave later.)  You need to use `malloc` to allocate memory that isn't local to the function.
- You're assigning to `data[5]`, but the array only goes up to `data[4]`.  (Remember that arrays are zero-based, so the highest array index is one less than the size.)

Here's a version that should work correctly:

```
char * function(char a)
{
  char *data = malloc(3);  // 2 for the hex digits, plus 1 for the null
  sprintf(data, "%02X", a);
  data[2] = '\0';
  return data;
}
```

After you call this function, you need to free the string when you're done with it.  Here's an example `main` function:

```
int main()
{
  char *str = function('a');
  printf("Test: %s\n", str);
  free(str);  // Release the memory allocated by malloc()
}
```

Comment: It still gives the same warning.!

Comment: It didn't when I compiled it.  I've edited my answer to show the `main()` function that I used.

Answer (score -1):

You need not to return the string back because string is passed by reference in C by default. changes you made inside the function will affect the actual string.

Comment: There isn't pass by reference in C

Comment: And there *is* no string outside the function.  It's modifying the `data` array, which only exists while the function is running.